# Switching between two sine waves using analog circuitry

Tags: analog, frequency, sound, sine

I'm trying to do a project entirely using analog circuitry.  The project involves switching between two sine waves at a constant frequency to power a speaker.  I am using a Wien-bridge oscillator to create the sine waves at specific frequencies.  Is there a way to switch the output of the two waves in a clever way?

Comment: Other than an op-amp based analog switch?

Comment: Maybe a pair of JFETs? Google "JFET multiplexer"

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use one wien bridge oscillator and use "analogue" switches to alter the resistor values in the oscillator. At least this way the changeover from one frequency to another is self-synchronizing and possibly won't "glitch" the speaker as it might if you used two wien oscillators.

If you do decide to use two oscillators then use analogue switches for selecting one output or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use a 4053 or DGS series analog switch (depending on your supply voltages etc.

One thing you could do is to fade between the two oscillator outputs using a pair of analog multipliers, which might make for a more pleasing click-free transition.